# Does the SDK have built in swipe detection?

Tags: android

There are many questions about *how* to detect swipes in Android, however in this question I am asking *if* the SDK has a built in swipe gesture recognizer.

I have searched

1. The Android developer documentation.
2. Stack Overflow.
3. The web in general.

and all I can find are custom implementations based on GestureDetector.

I do not like the idea of implementing a custom swipe detector as it may not behave exactly like other swipe detectors in other apps (and no longer matching the user's mental model of how swipes work)

**TLDR: Does the Android SDK have built in swipe detection?**

Comment: What do you consider "swipe" to be that is different from a fling, [which is supported directly by `GestureDetector`](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-a-subset-of-supported-gestures)?

Comment: in which context you want to use swipe detection? For example in RecyclerView you can implement SimpleItemTouchHelper which handles swipes.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was thinking of something like [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) where the OS has a standard velocity and distance required to trigger the event (that way my app would be consistent with every other app). If not onFling looks like it would be the way to go (Thanks for pointing it out!).

Comment: There should be some logic in `GestureDetector` that distinguishes a drag from a fling, and that presumably takes velocity into account. Otherwise, I don't think that there is a direct analogue of that iOS construct, though I'm not an iOS developer, so I cannot state for certain.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, it does make sense that `GestureDetector` would differentiate to some degree. Thanks!

Comment: @Csongi77 I am trying to detect a left or right swipe made over a fullscreen web view so I can trigger a Javascript function (detecting the swipe in Javascript has been unreliable across different devices)